# Caratheodory adiabatic inaccessibility with more than one deformation variable

Tags: thermodynamics, differential-geometry

On page 33 and 34 Kirkwood & Oppenheim prove that Caratheodory's principle of adiabatic inaccessibility is equivalent to the Clausisus-Kelvin principles for a single thermal variable *t*, the empirical temperature and one deformation variable *x*, see [https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015004522580&view=1up&seq=48&skin=2021]. On page 34 they write that the proof can be extended for more than one deformation variable:

> If the states of the system are functions of *t* and more than one other parameter, we note that the conclusions drawn from Fig. 4-1 hold for any plane in the space of the variables characterizing the system that is parallel to the *t* axis. Thus the region around *1* that is inaccessible adiabatically from *1* may be rotated about *1*, thereby sweeping out a finite volume inaccessible adiabatically from *1*. This volume includes points that are arbitrarily close to *1*. We note that reversible adiabatic paths through 1 are restricted to lying on a surface through *1*.

(In the quote above *1* refers to point 1 on the plot 4-1 and *t* is the empirical temperature)

Can somebody help me to decipher the meaning of this?